# How .net manage memory reference sharing?

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I have a class with one property

```
public class Test 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }  
}

private void TestReference()
{
    Test tst1 = new Test();
    tst1.Name = "ASP.NET";
    Test tst2 = tst1;
    tst1.Name = "JAVA";
    string name = tst2.Name; // Shows "JAVA" because of reference sharing 

    tst1 = null;

    bool isNullObj = tst2 == null; // isNullObj is false 
}
```

In above example when I set `tst.Name = "JAVA"` this change also reflect in  `tst2.Name` because of reference sharing, this I understand but when I set `tst = null;` `tst2`is still alive.
my question is, if it is sharing reference! why `tst2` is still alive?

Comment: I think people don't like the way you've formatted your question, e.g. "Want to understand reference sharing" isn't really a question.

Comment: `Reference sharing` isnt a thing, what you are describing is assigning values by reference

Comment: @paqogomez He is not assigning a single value by reference.  He is however sharing a reference to a value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tst1` and `tst2` are variables which hold reference to objects in memory. If both point to same object, then you can change object via any of references.

If you resign a reference to one of variables, the other variable will still hold its reference. That's why setting `tst1` to `null` (or to any other value) does not affect `tst2`.

Here is what you have in memory:

[image]

Comment: now I understand the concept. One more question if I want to set that referenced memory location to null so that all referenced object for that memory should also be null how can I do it?

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta I added picture which shows how objects in memory look like. Regarding your question - .NET has automatic memory allocation and freeing. If there is no references to some object on heap (i.e. if both tst1 and tst2 are set to null or deleted from stack when you exit the method), then during next garbage collection, Test object instance will be considered as garbage and removed

Answer (score 2):

This (oddly enough) makes more sense when you think of references as pointers.

When I write:

```
tst1.Name = "JAVA";
```

I am going through the pointer and modifying the object itself. However, when I write:

```
tst1 = null;
```

I am just setting the variable (of pointer type) to null. The object it was pointing to is not affected. Thus,

```
tst2 == null
```

Will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this case, without [Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx):

```
int a = 1;  // a = 1
int b = a;  // a = 1, b = 1
a = 2;      // a = 2, b = 1
            // a == b -> false
```

This is the *same* thing that is happening with the presented code in the question. For reference types, only a *reference value* (or the "reference to an object") is stored in the variable. However, the variables themselves are separate and reassignment to one does *not* affect any other variable.

(The "sharing" behavior is explained because multiple variables, as in the question, can contain the *same* reference value and thus refer to the *same* object.)